Changing variables in double integral.
To evaluate the integral
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-x}(y-x)\sqrt{x+y}dydx$$
I have to change the variables to $u=y-x$ and $v=x+y$.
I know that
$$x=-\frac{u}{2}+\frac{v}{2},\qquad y=\frac{u}{2}+\frac{v}{2}$$
Hence
$$dydx=\frac{1}{2}dudv$$
I have some doubts about the new range of integration.
Since $0\leq x\leq1$, then
$$0\leq-\frac{u}{2}+\frac{v}{2}\leq1\Rightarrow u\leq v\leq2+u$$
However, from $0\leq y\leq1-x$, I just got
$$0\leq u+v\leq2+u-v$$
So, $u$ and $v$ are both dependent on each other.
I am not getting the new range of integration.

What's your doubt specifically? What would the limits of integration be in the new case?

@Conreu yes, that is.

Pictorial Way :
We can see that the Original Area is the Shaded Part.
Every Purple line is $x+y=c$ , where $c$ is a Constant.
Naturally $c$ varies independently from $0$ (line though the Origin) to $1$ (line matching the triangle)
In other words , $v=x+y=c$ gives the limits from $v=0$ to $v=1$

Every Green line is $y-x=k$ where $k$ is a Constant.
We see that $k$ varies with $v=x+y=c$ from Starting Point $(c,0)$ for a Purple line to Ending Point $(0,c)$ for that Purple line
That gives us the limits from $k=y-x=0-c=-c=-v$ to $k=y-x=c-0=+v$
In other words , $u=y-x=k$ gives the limits from $u=-v$ to $u=+v$
Specific Example :
Consider the Middle Purple line : Starting from $(0.5,0)$ & Ending at $(0,0.5)$ , it will have $v=0.5$
It will the Green line limits from $u=0-0.5=-0.5=-v$ to $u=0.5-0=+0.5=+v$
ADDENDUM :
With the Image , we can see that we can easily change order from $dxdy$ to $dydx$ [[ Due to Symmetry ]]
More-over the Image gives us the limits for order change from $dudv$ to $dvdu$ via the Blue line making 2 half triangles :
Upper half triangle :
Variable $u$ will go from $u=-1$ to $u=0$
While variable $v$ will go from $v=+u$ to $v=1$
Lower half triangle :
Variable $u$ will go from $u=0$ to $u=+1$
While variable $v$ will go from $v=-u$ to $v=1$

The region of integration in the $xy$-plane is a triangle with vertices $(0,0),(1,0),$ and $(0,1)$. The change of variables $(x,y)\mapsto(v,u)=(x+y,y-x)$ maps it into another triangle in the $vu$-plane with vertices $(0,0),(1,-1),$ and $(1,1)$. Therefore, the integral in the $vu$-plane is given by
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\int_{-v}^v u\sqrt{v}\,dudv.
$$
